# Passing label.text through application layers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a multilayer website (asp C#).  I am curious how I can access set a label text from inside the business layer.  Currently it says it can not resolve the symbol but I have it in my presentation layer.  Is there a way to pass through all the layers and set the label.Text?

Basically I want to do my validation in the Business layer not on the presentation layer but I need to be able to set the label when the validation fails.

```
public CommandResponse<int> AddRequest(AddRequestCommand command)
    {
        CommandResponse<int> response = new CommandResponse<int>();
        //DO domain logic
        using (var context = ContextFactory.GetContext())
        {
            var repo = RepositoryFactory.GetRequestRepository(context);
            string email = command.Request.RecipientEmail;
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
            Match match = regex.Match(email);
            if (!match.Success)
            {
                lblEmailmsg.Text = "Error Message"
            }



            var id = repo.Add(command.Request);

            response.Id = id;
            response.IsSuccessful = true;

            DomainEvents.Raise<RequestCreatedEvent>(new  RequestCreatedEvent(command.Request, command.Request.Token ));
        }
```

Comment: How are you *trying* to do this that's currently failing?  `label.Text` is just a string.  Passing a string to a method and/or returning a string from a method should both work just fine.

Comment: I feel like there is not nearly enough information presented about the specific issue you are facing. Do you have any sample of code that can demonstrate the problem you are having?

Comment: lblEmailMsg.Text = "Please use a valid email address"

Comment: nice start. welcome to developing web applications. yes. you should pass your "Text" property from you Page code to business layer. do not try to reach any client (your page) from any server (your busines layer).

Comment: @franburr: That line of code should work anywhere that `lblEmailMsg` is defined.  Which should only be on the page, really.  The business logic shouldn't be able to see presentation layer code, it should be the other way around.  The presentation layer should invoke the business logic.  And in doing so provide and receive the raw values it needs to populate the items in the presentation.  (In this case a string.)

Comment: @David I guess what I don't understand is how to alert the user when the validation fails other than using a label.  I have been searching for help online all morning without much luck.  Do you know of any sites that may help me out?

Comment: Or should I use validation in both places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're trying to do something like this:

```
public class SomethingInThePresentationLayer
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var businessObject = new SomethingInTheBusinessLayer();
        businessObject.Validate();
    }
}

public class SomethingInTheBusinessLayer
{
    public void Validate()
    {
        pageElement.Text = "This is the text.";
    }
}
```

This is incorrect, for a couple of reasons.  First, classes can't see each other's members like that.  `SomethingInTheBusinessLayer` would need a reference to the `pageElement` member in order to use it.

Second, this is mixing concerns.  `pageElement` is a presentation layer element.  It is wholly owned by the presentation layer and nothing in the business layer should know about it.  This is *especially* true is understanding it requires referencing libraries which the business layer shouldn't reference (such as `System.Web`).

Instead, when interacting with the business layer, you would use more portable types.  They can be custom types exposed by the business layer itself, or just the primitive types of the values you're using.  For example, you might have something like this:

```
public class SomethingInThePresentationLayer
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var businessObject = new SomethingInTheBusinessLayer();
        var result = businessObject.Validate();
        pageElement.Text = result;
    }
}

public class SomethingInTheBusinessLayer
{
    public string Validate()
    {
        return "This is the text";
    }
}
```

Now the business layer *only* performs the logic, it doesn't try to interact with the presentation elements.  That's a job for the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little thin on details, but from your last sentence:

> Basically I want to do my validation in the Business layer not on the
>   presentation layer but I need to be able to set the label when the
>   validation fails.

I think I know what you mean.

Here's how I would do this kind of thing:

Use Ajax/JSON to send the data to the server.  Process what you need including all validations there, then send JSON data back to the client (which is then available in the 'success' handler of your Ajax call) including any label text that needs to be updated.

You can then take this result and do what you need to do with JS/jQuery including updating labels and so on.  Also, Knockout.js is an excellent tool (among several) that can simplify this type of client-side data binding.

Comment: Thank you I will give it a shot.  I would up vote you but people have killed my rep points voting this question down.